# Count collisions in n-Queens problem in Python

Tags: python, matrix, genetic-algorithm, n-queens

I started working on python for AI and I'm having some problems:

I have an n- Queens problem  [here is a detailed explanation of the problem](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/queens)

The fitness function receives a an array of the form:

```
decoded =  [3, 1, 2, 5 ... n]
```

where the element corresponds to the X coordinate and the index corresponds to the Y coordinate
i.e. taking the coordinates from the example above:

```
# [X, Y]
pairCoords = [[3,0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [5, 1], ... [n, z]]
```

so I have the fitness function which recieves a similar array to the first example.
var record starts with the max number of collisions **n*(n-1)** and decreases with each collision found

```
    def fitness(self, decodedGenes):
    record = self.numeroN * (self.numeroN-1)

    for y in range(len(decodedGenes)):
        if self.positionIsAtacking(decodedGenes, decodedGenes[y], y):
            record = record - 1
    return record
```

so a best case world return **n*(n-1)** and a worst case would return 0

the auxiliar function it calls checks a given X and Y coordinates and returns if there is a collision but it's not working

```
    def positionIsAtacking(self, coords, X, Y):
    for i in range(len(coords)):
        # Check Y
        if (coords[i] == Y):
            return True
        # Check Diagonals
        if (coords[i] - Y == i - X):
            return True
        if (coords[i] - Y == X - i):
            return True
    return False
```

I have tried changing the parameters but I do not know where to search anymore I think the second function doesn`t work or maybe y changed x and y

Answer (score 0):

```
def fitness(self, cromosoma):
    record = self.numeroN * (self.numeroN - 1)

    for row in range(len(board)):
        decodedGenes.append(self.decodeGene(board[row]))

    for y in range(len(decodedGenes)):
        x = decodedGenes[y]
        record = record - self.collisions(decodedGenes, x, y)
    return record
def collisions(self, coords, X, Y):
    board = []
    r = 0
    for i in range(len(coords)):
        board.append([0] * self.numeroN)
    for y in range(len(coords)):
        board[y][coords[y]] = 1

    for y in range(len(board)):
        for x in range(len(board)):
            # if has Queen and is not the same
            if board[y][x] == 1 and y != Y:
                # check x
                if x == X:
                    r = r + 1
                # check Diagonals
                if self.crash_diagonal(x, y, X, Y):
                    r = r + 1
    return r

def crash_diagonal(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    dx = abs(x1 - x2)
    dy = abs(y1 - y2)
    return dx == dy
```